# Flow Formula not correct

Tags: formula-field

I'm sure this is simple...  I have a formula field that calculates square footage of a rug.  I am using this resulting field in a Screenflow ( Not connected to any object ) to run a quick estimate template. I set up radio buttons for Types of rug ( 3 Choices ) that have 3 different price results.  The following is the formula I am using for resulting field of ( Sq Ft total {!wtf} x 8, 9, or 15.00 ) for amount result field.

IT IS ONLY CALCULATING THE $8 price as a result no matter what is picked.

```
{!wtf}
*
CASE({!Select_Rug_Type},
    {!EightDollarRugs}, 8.00,
    {!NineDollarRugs}, 9.00,
    {!SpecialPriceRugs},15.00,
    Null
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this way

{!wtf}
*
CASE(Select_Rug_Type,
"EightDollarRugs", "8.00",
"NineDollarRugs", "9.00",
"SpecialPriceRugs","15.00",
"Null")

Comment: I will run this a bit later and tyvm.  I was so mad there is no syntex generator in Flow so hard to know whats wrong if your not very up on it.  I ended up doing the " rigged " cheat way and just added a decision element and then sent the putputs of the 3 different items to three cloned screens each with the simple formula of {!wtf} * 9.00  etc.  Works like a charm but obviously not the easy way.  I just got tired of playing with commas and dots all day getting nowhere LOL  TYVM paven!!!!